# Make category as subdomain in magento

Tags: php, magento, subdomain, categories

I need to accomplish the following task:

I have to put every category in my store as subdomain of my store:

Follow an example:

`www.mystore.com/category => category.mystore.com`

This is a new best practice in SEO that is taking the top of the hill and I would like to understand how this can be accomplished in magento considering that we're not talking about a simple blog, but a complex e-commerce with session and cart.

Comment: you can create multistore for each category and point that with different domains.

Comment: Ok, this is appreciated. Let's consider that I have already set up one multi-store and I have a subdomain that is pointing to it (I'll have 4 multi-store in total and domains at the end). All I need now is to make this multi-store displaying all products in a current category. How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1st create one root category. Then while you creating the multistore you can choose root category for the store

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try. I'll let you know if it was ok :)